# Linker Error undefined symbols C++

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I have been getting a lot of trouble from linker errors.  This is the most recent one I have gotten.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"XMLObject::~XMLObject()", referenced from:
  Hash::addFile(char*, XMLObject) in hash.o
  std::__1::__split_buffer<XMLObject, std::__1::allocator<XMLObject>&>::~__split_buffer() in hash.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get it when i add a hash table (.h and .cpp).  I really dont know what could cause this error.

```
void Hash::addObj(char* id, XMLObject num)
{
int index = hash(id);
if(hashTable[index]->identifier == "empty") // checks empty bucket
{
    hashTable[index]->identifier = id;
    hashTable[index]->files.push_back(num);
}
else // checks list
{
    bool check = false; // true if id word was found
    item* ptr = hashTable[index];
    while(ptr != nullptr)
    {
        if(ptr->identifier == id)
        {
            ptr->files.push_back(num);
            check = true;
            break;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    if(!check)
    {
        item* n = new item;
        n->identifier = id;
        n->files.push_back(num);
        n->next = nullptr;
        ptr = n;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Show the code of `Hash::addFile()` in .h and .cpp.

Comment: Just added the method @herohuyongtao

Comment: Please, for goodness sake, **don't implement your own hash.** C++ has perfectly good [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and if you are stuck in C++03, there are plenty of suitable implementations lying around on the internet, e.g. in [Boost.Unordered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/unordered/). Unless you do it for learning, but then you probably shouldn't be making it specific to some other kind of object anyway.

Comment: I have to for the project.  This is a school assignment and we had to create our own.  For all of you who go to complain im asking to solve homework, this project is to create a XML Search Engine so the hash table is just a small part.  Not just a hwk problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you added to your project `hash.h` and `hash.cpp`, but that module depends on another one, maybe `xmlobject.h` and `xmlobject.cpp`.

Solution: add these other files to the project too.

Comment: @user3525456: If `xmlobject.cpp` is already in the project, then the problem is probably that it is missing the definition of the class destructor: `XmlObject::~XmlObject()` so you should write it. Or maybe it is written in another file? Note that nothing in C++ prevents you from splitting your member class definitions across several files.